# New Material icons

Tags: html, material-design, google-material-icons

I was searching for a new icon in https://material.io/icons, and I found a renovated icons with outline, baseline, rounded, two tones, and sharp versions. So, I want to know If somebody knows how to implement the new icons in that versions, also we can animate that icons. When I try to copy the tag in any version, I obtain de same tag, and my web look like normal, not renovated.
https://material.io/tools/icons/

Comment: I have the same issue: can't find info about Google Material Icons and usage of outlined style via webfont. Does anybody knows?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to not have been implemented yet, here is the GitHub issue:

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/773